# Advanced Filtering in Laravel 5.1 using mmanos/laravel-search

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and using mmanos/laravel-search for searching locally on my api. I need to add filtering ability on the price column.

Example: If I have items with id,name,...,price and I need to search and filter price such that "price < 1000" or "price > 1000". 
How can I implement such feature using mmanos search or any other method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you said "column" - can you confirm that you are using a supported full text search service (Elasticsearch, Algolia, and ZendSearch) or are you storing data in a relational database? If the latter, you don't want this package.

Comment: Yes i am using ZendSearch through mmanos/laravel-search package.